# Apply for production access, play console

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have created a new developer account and now when i create a new app (and after filling all the information about the app) it says apply for production (and the app is in review but the app status is inactive).

by reading this :  [article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/14151465)
i believe i should have to first add the app in testing to get the publishing access as my account is a personal account. is that correct ? if yes than is there a way to avoid this, i want to publish my apps right away. can i convert my account type? or any other possible solution

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic